# constructing principal $G$-bundles over a topological space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, lie-groups, principal-bundles

Let $G$ be an abelian Lie group, and let $X$ be a topological space. I know that principal $G$-bundles over $X$ can be classified by the cohomology group $\check{H}^1(X,G)$. Since $G$ is abelian, $\check{H}^1(X,G)$ is isomorphic to $H^2(X,G)$. For a given non-trivial principal $G$-bundle $\pi:P \to X$, If $H^2(X,G)$ be isomorphic to $Z$, is it possible to construct other principal $G$-bundles over $X$ from $\pi$? If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: It is not true that the first cech cohomology is isomorphic to the second singular cohomology for an abelian group. Is this what you meant in your third sentence? You can actually make this work for nonabelian groups as well!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @AndresMejia You mean that for every Lie group $G$, $\check{H}^1(X,G) \cong H^2(X,G)$?